# Accessing RTC(DS1307) through I2C in ATmega16

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, i2c, avr-gcc, real-time-clock

I have written a code to access RTC(DS1307) through I2C using ATmega16 and I am using compiler AVR Studio 4.

Code is given below:-

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

void rtc_init(void)
{
TWSR=0x00;
TWBR=0x47;
TWCR=0x04;

}

void rtc_start(void)
{
TWCR=(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWINT);

while(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)==0);

}


unsigned char rtc_read(void)
{
TWCR=(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
return(TWDR);
}

void rtc_write(unsigned char data)
{
TWDR=data;// sending address
TWCR=(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
while(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)==0);
}

void rtc_stop()
{
TWCR=(1<<TWINT)|(TWSTO)|(1<<TWEN);
while(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)==0);

}

main()
{
unsigned char sec,min,hr;
DDRA=0xFF;
DDRB=0xFF;


rtc_init();
_delay_ms(1000);

rtc_start();

rtc_write(0b11010000);   // 1101000=adress of ds1307 and bit 0= write   
rtc_write(0x00);  // pointing address location 00 i.e seconds
rtc_write(0x00);// set sec=0
rtc_write(0x00);// set min=0
rtc_write(0x00);// set hr=0

rtc_stop();


while(1)
{

rtc_start();
rtc_write(0b11010001);   // 1101000=adress of ds1307 and bit 1= read   
rtc_write(0x00);  // pointing address location 00 i.e seconds
sec=rtc_read();
rtc_stop();
PORTA=sec;
PORTB=0x01;
_delay_ms(5000);
rtc_start();
rtc_write(0b11010001);   // 1101000=adress of ds1307 and bit 1= read   
rtc_write(0x01);  // pointing address location 00 i.e seconds
min=rtc_read();
rtc_stop();
PORTA=min;
PORTB=0x02;
_delay_ms(5000);
rtc_start();
rtc_write(0b11010001);   // 1101000=adress of ds1307 and bit 1= read   

hr=rtc_read();
rtc_stop();
PORTA=hr;
PORTB=0b00000100;
_delay_ms(5000);
}
}
```

I have successfully build the above code. When I am running this code on PROTEUS simulator I am not getting any output, but polling in the code working properly for applying delay.

I want to know where I have done wrong and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are generating the start condition correctly, among other things.  From the datasheet (page 183):

> The first step in a TWI transmission is to transmit a START condition.
>   This is done by writing a specific value into TWCR, instructing the
>   TWI hardware to transmit a START condition. Which value to write is
>   described later on. However, it is important that the TWINT bit is set
>   in the value written. Writing a one to TWINT clears the flag. The TWI
>   will not start any operation as long as the TWINT bit in TWCR is set.
>   Immediately after the application has cleared TWINT, the TWI will
>   initiate transmission of the START condition.

There is a detailed C example in the datasheet that looks like this:

```
TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN)  //Send START condition
while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));           // Wait for TWINT Flag set. This indicates
                                        // that the START condition has been transmitted
if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != START)             // Check value of TWI Status Register. Mask
    ERROR();                            // prescaler bits. If status different from
                                        // START go to ERROR
TWDR = SLA_W;                           // Load SLA_W into TWDR Register. Clear
TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);          // TWINT bit in TWCR to start transmission
                                        // of address
while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));           // Wait for TWINT Flag set. This indicates
                                        // that the SLA+W has been transmitted,
                                        // and ACK/NACK has been received.
if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != MT_SLA_ACK)        // Check value of TWI Status Register. Mask
    ERROR();                            // prescaler bits. If status different from
                                        // MT_SLA_ACK go to ERROR
TWDR = DATA;                            // Load DATA into TWDR Register. Clear
TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);          // TWINT bit in TWCR to start transmission
                                        // of data
while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));           // Wait for TWINT Flag set. This indicates
                                        // that the DATA has been transmitted, and
                                        // ACK/NACK has been received.
if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != MT_DATA_ACK)       // Check value of TWI Status Register. Mask
    ERROR();                            // prescaler bits. If status different from
                                        // MT_DATA_ACK go to ERROR
TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWSTO); // Transmit STOP condition
```

That is very different from your code.  I'd start with the sample from the datasheet, and go from there.